# Running ApScheduler in Gunicorn Without Duplicating Per Worker

Tags: python, uwsgi, gunicorn, apscheduler

The title basically says it all. I have gunicorn running my app with 5 workers. I have a data structure that all the workers need access to that is being updated on a schedule by apscheduler. Currently apscheduler is being run once per worker, but I just want it run once period. Is there a way to do this? I've tried using the `--preload` option, which let's me load the shared data structure just once, but doesn't seem to let all the workers have access to it when it updates. I'm open to switching to uWSGI if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any way to do this with either, at least not without some sort of RPC. That is, run APScheduler in a separate process and then connect to it from each worker. You may want to look up projects like RPyC and Execnet to do that.